# How to solve the step 5 in harbor installing

Tags: docker, harbor

when I run the "install.sh" , the step 5 will run a long time that like the picture showing.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WNMfI.png)
I download the offline source and how to solve the question ? Thanks.

I have configure the daemon.json in docker.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.